# Excessive Memory Consumption in blank-ish WinForms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory

Why is my Windows Forms application consuming more and more memory when it's a blank app and not even being used by the user (me)?

You may be able to reproduce with these steps:

1. Open Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
2. `New Project` > `C#` > `Windows Forms Application` > `.NET Framework 4.5`
3. Add a `PictureBox` to `Form1` from the `Toolbox` pane
4. Right-click the `PictureBox` and select `Choose Image...`
5. Select [image: Loading Animation] GIF file
6. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
7. Open `Task Manager` and watch the memory go up by N KB's every second.

This is driving me nuts for the obvious reason. My app starts off at about <1MB and within a matter of a few minutes, it's up to ~10MB. Give it a few more minutes and it's up again to ~40MB. And it doesn't stop there. In fact, I left it running over night and when I woke up, the PC was unresponsive.

Comment: Use a memory profiler to see what objects in your app are taking that much memory.

Comment: Does this happen outside of the debugger?

Comment: No repro, can't say I expected one.  Just normal gen#0 build up and then settles into ~5.6M private memory usage after the first collection occurs.  You'll need to look for environmental problems, that usually starts at anti-malware and other non-standard addons.

Comment: I cannot repro it either but I have .NET 4.5.2 installed. Can you try it again with .NET 4.5.2 installed?

Comment: Doesn't happen with w8.1, 64bit, vs2013x, up2, .Net 4.5.5

Comment: Thank you @HighCore, HansPassant, Alois, TaW and Admiral: This happens both when debugging and also when I just run the exe directly from the bin/release folders.

Answer (score 0):

The GC is not collecting unused memory, since it's is very small.

You can try forcing the GC collect (not a good practice, just for testing)

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = 10000;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

After this the memory stays at 3.2 MB at my PC :)